# Save command output to variable without it printing to standard output

Tags: linux, bash

I'm doing a bash script and I'm grabbing the output from this command:

```
fpings=$(fping -c 1 -t 1 $ips | sort)
```

The `fpings` variable does contain the output from the command, and the actual output of the command is not printed to the shell, but it still writes a line to the shell for each ip pinged.

There is a switch (`-q`) to suppress the output (the part that I want) but not any to suppress the part I don't want.

How do I get the result from the fpings command without it printing stuff to the shell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do not want to see the standard error, redirect it to `/dev/null`:

```
fpings=$(fping -c 1 -t 1 $ips 2>/dev/null | sort)
```

Comment: The problem is that `fping` outputs to stderr only. So if you remove stderr...

Answer (score 4):

```
fpings=$( {fping -c 1 -t 1 $ips | sort; } 2>&1 )
```

should work  the {} capture everything and then it redirects both streams (out and err) to just out and saves in the variable

Comment: Using `fpings=$( (fping -c 1 -t 1 $ips | sort; ) 2>&1 )` and then filtering out the errors worked.